# Connecting Amazon workspaces from excel vba

Tags: excel, amazon-web-services, vba

The actual task was to import the huge csv file with additional commas as part of the field value into SQL Server 2014 database. I developed a macro to split the csv file into small parts and then converting it as tab delimited and import into database using ADODB. This is the existing one at this moment.

Now Is there a way to connect to AWS and import the data into the tables? I know SO works around my initial effort but I am very new and could not really figure it out on approach.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Which AWS RDS are you using?

Comment: Please ignore this as this had become out of scope in my project now..Thanks for your time.